# How can I set http.port in application.conf by using playframework2.4(Scala)

Tags: scala, port, playframework-2.4

I could set http.port in applicaton.conf by using playframework1.2.7
like this

```
http.port = 9020
jpda.port = 8020
```

also jdpa.port.

But in play2.4.

I cannot set `http.port` in application.conf like this.

I know that I can do like this when I run this project.

```
activator "run 9020"
```

But it is too troublesome for me.

If you have some ideas,
please share your idea.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Thank you for replying!
Even if I set htttp.port in application.conf,
the project run at default port (:9000)

Comment: If I use Play1.2.7,
I could set http.port in application.conf like this.

```
http.port = 9020
```

and
the project runs at 9020 port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot specify port in aaplication.conf during run mode (but this can be used while deploying).

> In run mode the HTTP server part of Play starts before the application has been compiled. This means that the HTTP server cannot access the application.conf file when it starts. If you want to override HTTP server settings while using the run command you cannot use the application.conf file. Instead, you need to either use system properties or the devSettings setting shown above.

Source: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Configuration#HTTP-server-settings-in-application.conf

Also look at full server configuration options
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ProductionConfiguration#Server-configuration-options

Comment: Thank you so much!
I will look at these documents.